Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{K} |sin(n)|^{\alpha n}$?
I had seen a very surprising result where $|sin(n)|^{n}$ is a divergent series. I was wondering if this analysis extends to different exponents as a function of n, in particular a constant multiple of $n$.
I know that for some P >= 1/2 , the series $sin(n)/n^{p}$ converges, and that $\frac{|sin(n)|^{n}}{n}$ is a convergent series, but I hadn't seen a thorough study of $|sin(n)|^{an}$ and whether it converges or diverges. My intuition is that it should converge if $a$ is greater than 1 but I fail to prove the result.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

To clarify, are you interested in a finite sum of $|\sin(n)|^{\alpha n}$, or the behavior of $\lim_{K\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^K |\sin(n)|^{\alpha n}$? Your title suggests the former, while your question suggests the latter.
